# Transform community data into wide-format for vegan package

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation, vegan

I am trying to analyze some community data with the `vegan` package. I have my data in the wrong format, and am looking for ways to change the format.
What I have is something like this:

```
Habitat          Species        Abundance
1                  A                3
2                  B                2
3                  C                1
1                  D                5
2                  A                8
3                  F                4
```

And what I think I need is:

```
Habitat      Species A       Species B       Species C    Species D    Species D
1                3               0              0              5          0
2                8               ...... etc
3                0
```

Or is there any other format that `vegan` can take? I am trying to calculate similarity in species composition between habitats.

Comment: Hi Karla and welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

The function [**`matrify()`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/labdsv/versions/1.8-0/topics/matrify) in the `labdsv` package does *exactly* this for community analyses.

> Takes a data.frame in three column form (sample.id, taxon, abundance) and converts it into full matrix form, and then exports it as data.frame with the appropriate row.names and column names.

In other words, it converts your data from long to wide format so that each `row` represents a *sample* (in your case "habitat"; sometimes this would be a "plot"), each `column` represents a *species*, and each `cell` shows the *abundance* of the given cell's species (`column`) in the given cell's habitat (`row`).

**Example**:

```
dat <- data.frame(Habitat = c('Hab1','Hab1','Hab2','Hab2','Hab2','Hab3','Hab3'),
                  Species = c('Sp1','Sp2','Sp1','Sp3','Sp4','Sp2','Sp3'),
                  Abundance = c(1,2,1,3,2,2,1))

print(dat)

  Habitat Species Abundance
1    Hab1     Sp1         1
2    Hab1     Sp2         2
3    Hab2     Sp1         1
4    Hab2     Sp3         3
5    Hab2     Sp4         2
6    Hab3     Sp2         2
7    Hab3     Sp3         1

library(labdsv)
matrify(dat)

     Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4
Hab1   1   2   0   0
Hab2   1   0   3   2
Hab3   0   2   1   0
```

---

#### Bonus:

I rewrote `matrify` many years ago so that it could handle **[*longitudinal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_study) community data**

- Specifically, my `matrify2()` function creates rows for each **plot-year** combination (i.e., resampled rows for the same plot) by duplicating plot (or habitat) row monikers and adding a `Year` column.

Below is the code:

```
#Create data.frame with PLOT, YEAR, and ABUNDANCE for each SPEC:

 #Creates function that can sort the data.frame output by:
   #Columns = individual SPECS, #Rows = plot by Year
   #Note: Code modified from matrify() function from labdsv package (v. 1.6-1)

 matrify2 <-  function(data) { 
   #Data must have columns: plot, SPEC, abundance measure,Year 
   if (ncol(data) != 4) 
       stop("data frame must have four column format")
   plt <- factor(data[, 1]) 
   spc <- factor(data[, 2])
   abu <- data[, 3]
   yrs <- factor(data[, 4])
   plt.codes <- sort(levels(factor(plt)))                                                     ##object with sorted plot numbers
   spc.codes <- levels(factor(spc))                                                           ##object with sorted SPEC names
   yrs.codes <- sort(levels(factor(yrs)))                                                     ##object with sorted sampling Years
   taxa <- matrix(0, nrow = length(plt.codes)*length(yrs.codes), ncol = length(spc.codes))    ##Create empty matrix with proper dimensions (unique(plotxYear) by # of SPEC)
   plt.list <- rep(plt.codes,length(yrs.codes))                                               ##Create a list of all the plot numbers (in order of input data) to add as an ID column at end of function
   yrs.list <- rep(yrs.codes,each=length(plt.codes))                                          ##Create a list of all the Year numbers (in order of input data) to add as an ID column at end of function
   col <- match(spc, spc.codes)                                                               ##object that determines the alphabetical order ranking of each SPEC in the spc.code list
   row.plt <- match(plt, plt.codes)                                                           ##object that determines the rank order ranking of each plot of the input data in the plt.code list
   row.yrs <- match(yrs,yrs.codes)                                                            ##object that determines the rank order ranking of each Year of the input data in the yrs.code list
   for (i in 1:length(abu)) {
       row <- (row.plt[i])+length(plt.codes)*(row.yrs[i]-1)                                   ##Determine row number by assuming each row represents a specific plot & year in an object of rep(plot,each=Year)
       if(!is.na(abu[i])) {                                                                   ##ONly use value if !is.na .. [ignore all is.NA values]
         taxa[row, col[i]] <- sum(taxa[row, col[i]], abu[i])                                  ##Add abundance measure of row i to the proper SPEC column and plot/Year row. Sum across all identical individuals.
       }
   }
   taxa <- data.frame(taxa)                                                                   ##Convert to data.frame for easier manipulation
   taxa <- cbind(plt.list,yrs.list,taxa)                                                      ##Add ID columns for plot and Year to each row already representing the abundance of Each SPEC of that given plot/Year.
   names(taxa) <- c('Plot','Year',spc.codes)
   taxa
 }
```

**Example**:

```
dat.y <- data.frame(Habitat = c('Hab1','Hab1','Hab2','Hab2','Hab2','Hab3','Hab3','Hab1','Hab1','Hab2','Hab2','Hab2','Hab3','Hab3'),
                    Species = c('Sp1','Sp2','Sp1','Sp3','Sp4','Sp2','Sp3','Sp1','Sp2','Sp1','Sp3','Sp4','Sp2','Sp3'),
                    Abundance = c(1,2,1,3,2,2,1,1,2,1,3,2,2,1),
                    Year = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
print(dat.y)

   Habitat Species Abundance Year
1     Hab1     Sp1         1    1
2     Hab1     Sp2         2    1
3     Hab2     Sp1         1    1
4     Hab2     Sp3         3    1
5     Hab2     Sp4         2    1
6     Hab3     Sp2         2    1
7     Hab3     Sp3         1    1
8     Hab1     Sp1         1    2
9     Hab1     Sp2         2    2
10    Hab2     Sp1         1    2
11    Hab2     Sp3         3    2
12    Hab2     Sp4         2    2
13    Hab3     Sp2         2    2
14    Hab3     Sp3         1    2

matrify2(dat.y)

  Plot Year Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4
1 Hab1    1   1   2   0   0
2 Hab2    1   1   0   3   2
3 Hab3    1   0   2   1   0
4 Hab1    2   1   2   0   0
5 Hab2    2   1   0   3   2
6 Hab3    2   0   2   1   0
```

---

Also, FYI, you should get to know `labdsv` according to the `vegan` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/labdsv/labdsv.pdf):

> **Together with the `labdsv` package, the `vegan` package provides most standard tools of descriptive community analysis.**

Comment: You should likely also become familiar with lesser known `ecodist`, which provides additional benefits not available in `vegan`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to `spread` your data. For example:

```
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
  spread(Species, Abundance)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would so, using `dcast`:

- Create a data sample: `cc=data.frame(habitat=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),species=c('a','e','a','e','g','a'), abundance=sample(1:10000,6))`.

**Output** looks like this (Ignore first column as it is an automatic index created by the ouput operation in R. What is important is the columns):

```
> cc  
>  habitat species abundance  
> 1       1       a      7814  
> 2       2       e      7801  
> 3       3       a      9510  
> 4       1       e      7443  
> 5       2       g      2160  
> 6       3       a      4026  
>
```

- Now **melt**: `m=melt(cc, id.vars=c("habitat","species"))`. Output:

```
  habitat species  variable value
1       1       a abundance  7814
2       2       e abundance  7801
3       3       a abundance  9510
4       1       e abundance  7443
5       2       g abundance  2160
6       3       a abundance  4026
```

- Now **reshape**: `dcast(m,habitat~species,fun.aggregate=mean)`, which yields:

```
  habitat    a    e    g
1       1 7814 7443  NaN
2       2  NaN 7801 2160
3       3 6768  NaN  NaN
```

More info about *reshape* [here](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/).

Kf